# Dynamic Cross Tab in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table with the following data

```
Year | Age Group | Male | Female
2000 | 0 - 25    | 50   | 100
2000 | 26 above  | 40   | 75
2001 | 0 - 25    | 150  | 86
2001 | 26 above  | 65   | 83
```

I would like to create a cross tab in the following format

```
                |  Male   | Female
2000            |  90     | 175
       0 - 25   |  50     | 100
       26 above |  40     | 75
2001            |  215    | 169
       0 - 25   |  150    | 86
       26 above |  65     | 83
```

I will be very grateful for your assistance.

Comment: The only difference there is how you output it later, it wont come out of mysql like that, but you can do it easily through changing of the year code and outputting later.

Comment: I barely see any difference nor I can see any point doing this. Generate the table like this when outputting not while on MySQL side.

Comment: It looks like a task for data reporting service.

Comment: BugFinder, yes, it is more of the output however, I also have to add the totals for the years. So I group by year and then age groups. 

AndriusNaruševičius, to a user, it is much easier than having it in the original format

Comment: @Devart, yes, it is for data reporting purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4acd8/3):

```
select * from
(
select year,ageGroup,male,female from t
union all
select year,'' ageGroup,sum(male) male,sum(female) female 
from t group by year
) st
order by year,agegroup
```

Comment: I have added another column of country. How can I represent the same groupings by year, country, age group in the rows and then Male, female as the columns.