# Prepared Statement: How to join header

Tags: mysql, join, prepared-statement, pivot

I've got 2 tables where i want to join the header and the first column within an prepared statement. I've got managed to join the column, but how to join the header?

**Table1 :**

```
  ID |Name 
----------
  1  |  A  
  2  |  B  
  3  |  C  
  4  |  D  
  5  |  E
```

**Table2 :**

```
TeamA|TeamB|Won|Lost
--------------------
  1  |  2  | 5 | 3
  1  |  3  | 2 | 4
  1  |  4  | 9 | 1
  2  |  5  | 5 | 5
  3  |  1  | 2 | 4
```

**Result-Matrix:**

```
     |  A | B |  C | D | E
----------------------------
  A  |  0 | 2 | -2 | 8 | 0
  B  |  0 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0
  C  | -2 | 0 |  0 | 0 | 0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e22e/2)

Comment: If table1's values are static a case statement would work.  Otherwise you're using dynamic SQL, or using PHP/GUI to re-orient the data.  or.. something similar to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981891/dynamic-cross-tab-in-mysql would work.  Words to search on "Pivot", "Cross tab" "dynamic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the team names from the ids, you will have to join on the table twice.

If you know all the values, the static version of the code is:

```
select a.name teamA,
  max(case when b.name = 'A' then won - lost else 0 end) as A,
  max(case when b.name = 'B' then won - lost else 0 end) as B,
  max(case when b.name = 'C' then won - lost else 0 end) as C,
  max(case when b.name = 'D' then won - lost else 0 end) as D,
  max(case when b.name = 'E' then won - lost else 0 end) as E
from yourtable t
left join teams a
  on t.teama = a.id
left join teams b
  on t.teamb = b.id
group by a.name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e22e/31).

Then if you are using a prepared statement to create this dynamically, the code will be:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN TeamB = ''',
      TeamB,
      ''' THEN won - lost else 0 END) AS `',
      TeamB, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from
(
  select a.name TeamA,
    b.name TeamB,
    t.won,
    t.lost
  from yourtable t
  left join teams a
    on t.teama = a.id
  left join teams b
    on t.teamb = b.id
  order by teamb
) x;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT TeamA, ', @sql, ' 
           from
           (
             select a.name TeamA,
              b.name TeamB,
              t.won,
              t.lost
            from yourtable t
            left join teams a
              on t.teama = a.id
            left join teams b
              on t.teamb = b.id
           ) s
           group by TeamA');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e22e/30)

The result is:

```
| TEAMA |  A | B | C | D | E |
------------------------------
|     A |  0 | 2 | 0 | 8 | 0 |
|     B |  0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|     C | -2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```